# Big O vs Theta Vs Omega?

Tags: asymptotics

I was given the following recursive formula: L(m)=16L(m/2)+m and I want to find for which function f, L(m) is theta of f.

In other words L(m) is big O of f and also small omega of f.

---

What I did until now? Nearly 95% of the job but still not sure whether this is an omega or big O or theta...

Comment: If $a(n) = b(n)$ then all of the following are true: $a(n) = O(b(n))$, $a(n) = \Omega(b(n))$, $a(n) = \Theta(b(n))$.

Comment: and how this can help me?

Comment: I want tight bounds

Comment: The tightest bound possible on a function $f(n)$ is $f(n)$ itself.

Comment: To answer your question, for which function $f$ does $L(m) = \Theta(f(m))$ hold: you can take $f = L$.

Comment: How can a function be both a big O and a small omega for some another function?

Comment: @rus9384 I think OP means the big omega ($\Omega$) instead of the small omega ($\omega$), since he/she is looking for $\Theta(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved using the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). In your case:

$a = 16, b = 2, f(n) = n$

$c_{crit} = \log_b a = 4$

$f(n) \in O(n^1)$ , is less than $O(n^{c_{crit}})$. Thus using case 1, and the answer is

$L(n) \in \Theta(n^{c_{crit}})$

$L(n) \in \Theta(n^4)$

Answer (score 0):

Solution using series expansion:
\begin{align}
L(m) &= 16 \cdot L(m/2) + m \\
&= 16 \cdot (16 \cdot L(m/4) + m/2) + m\\
&= 16^{2}(16 \cdot L(m/8) + m/4) + 16 \cdot m/2 + m \\
&=...\\
&= 16^{t}\cdot L(2^{t}) + 16^{t-1} \cdot m/2^{t-1} + ... + 16 \cdot m/2 + m \\ 
\end{align}

Now, assuming that $L(1) = 1$ (although it is not mentioned explicitly in the problem statement, it is generally is the case).

Since, $t \leq \lceil \log m\rceil \leq \log m + 1$ (assuming $\log$ with base $2$)

we get,
\begin{align}
L(m) \leq m \cdot \frac{8^{t+1} - 1}{7}  \leq m \cdot \frac{64 \cdot m^{3} - 1}{7} \leq 10 \cdot m^{4} = O(m^{4})
\end{align}

Since, $t \geq \lfloor \log m\rfloor \geq \log m - 1$.

we get,
\begin{align}
L(m) &\geq m \cdot \frac{8^{t+1} - 1}{7}  \\
&\geq m \cdot \frac{8^{\log m} - 1}{7} \\
&= m \cdot \frac{ m^{3} - 1}{7} \\
&\geq \frac{ m^{4}}{14}, \quad \quad \textrm{       for } m \geq 2 \\
&= \Omega(m^{4}) 
\end{align}

The definition of $\Omega$ allows us to assume the threshold to be greater than any positive constant. Therefore, in the last second inequality, I assumed $m \geq 2$.

This proves that $L(m ) = \Theta(m^4)$